# JavaScript for Automation (JXA) Excel open workbook question

Tags: javascript-automation

How do you open an Excel workbook using JavaScript for Automation?

```
let excelApp = Application("Microsoft Excel");  
let path = Path("/Users/me/Test.xlsx");
excelApp.openWorkbook(path);
```

gets error 50 "parameter error".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out:

```
let excelApp = Application("Microsoft Excel");
let testWorkbook = excelApp.openWorkbook({workbookFileName: "/Users/me/Test.xlsx"});
```

I also figured out how to get the contents of the data:

```
let varr = testWorkbook.sheets["firstsheet"].usedRange.value();
```

source: [Yosemite JXA release notes](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/releasenotes/InterapplicationCommunication/RN-JavaScriptForAutomation/Articles/OSX10-10.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014508-CH109-SW1) and Script Editor dictionary entry for Microsoft Excel

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).